# changing url for security reason asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am writing an asp.net web application for internal automation.So, I am not thinking about SEO or user-friendly URLs. Just I want to change URLs for hide path and file name and query string. For example I want this URL "http://test.com/Admin/Create.aspx?id=345&name=pin" be shown for user something else that is not understandable like an encrypted URL "http://test.com/enc=nidfvegvbervmxvpazxczxcwefve" or show all URLs in all formats in a same way like "http://test.com/".

I read some articles about URL rewriting and URL routing. However, I think their method work reversely. I mean when user write "http://test.com/products/book", these method could assume it as "http://test.com/products.aspx?type=book" but I want that user couldn't see real URL ever.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you might be looking for is `Server.Transfer` - check out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/540y83hx.aspx

Comment: I couldn't find any relation between Response.Redirect & Server.Transfer and my requirement!!

Comment: To implement this you would write a program, say called "RedirectMe.aspx", and in that program take the "enc" query parameter, look up in a database where that unique value should be going to (like "Create.aspx?id=345&name=pin") and then issue a `Server.Transfer("Create.aspx?id=345&name=pin", False)` (although depending upon your needs you may need to set the second parameter to "True"). What in this approach might not meet your requirement as stated?

Comment: OK, I got it but there is a real problem here; when I go to the second page with 'Server.Transfer("Create.aspx?id=345&name=pin")', I cannot get query strings. In fact 'Page.Request' gives me previous page's request. I need to work in second page normally after transfer.

Comment: Did you set the second parameter to `True`? This should give you the original query string. As for Page.Request, what specifically do you need to access in `Page.Request` that you cannot?

Comment: Yes, I tested it in both way (true, false); I couldn't get the second page's request.

Comment: I just ran a test for myself and all seemed to work as I had remembered.  When you say "you couldn't get the second page's request", what exactly do you mean by that? For example, does a statement like `Dim x = My.Request` (I'm a VB guy) not even compile? Or does it compile and, if so, what does the debugger say is the state of x in your Create.aspx application?

Comment: To clarify, Page.Request in second page (`create.aspx?id=345`) gets the specifications of first page(`RedirectMe.aspx`); however, I apparently need to get the second page's request. for example, when I check `Page.Request.Url`, it gets me `RedirectMe.aspx` instead of `create.aspx` and so on for other things like query string. I think the reason is that `Server.Transfer` works just in server side and Page.Request fills from client request. So, request might not be refreshed with `Server.Transfer`! Maybe!!

Comment: @Mojtaba Ah - I now see your point.  In that case, perhaps the simplest way to implement would be to do your database look-up once in RedirectMe.aspx just to determine which page should be the target of the redirection (i.e., Create.aspx) and then do a second look-up in Create.aspx again using the original query string to make any further decisions that are necessary.

Comment: Perhaps of interest: the first link that gets pulled up when searching (at least Google) for "Server.Transfer" appears to be old information (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800.aspx). This link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/caxa892w.aspx has more current information as some implementation details appear to have changed (e.g., you are not explicitly prohibited from trying to include a query string on the target of the Transfer, although as @Mojtaba found out these are effectively ignored).

Comment: Your suggestion has some maintenance problem; each developer in this project should be aware about `Page.Request` in pages that does not work properly and he should use look-up in database instead.

Comment: @Mojtaba Just move the look-up code sections into a function/class and have each target page call the function as its first step in Page_Init. Problem solved, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Just Encrypt the query string and decrypt on calling it

Something like

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-QueryString-Parameter-Values-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers